# MySql Start and End price (Min,Max) with Inner Joins

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a table of prices, 2 types. metal 1 and metal 2.

I have succeeded in getting the max, min price for each metal groups by day.

How can i also select the start (first) and end (last) of every day too?

I am nearly there, but struggling on getting these two final prices...

My SQL fiddle with example data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca4867/1

My query so far:

```
    select 
       highp.metal_price_datetime_IST AS high_price_metal_price_datetime_IST
     , highp.metal_price as highest_price
     , lowp.report_term
     , lowp.metal_id
     , lowp.metal_price as lowest_price
     , lowp.metal_price_datetime_IST AS low_price_metal_price_datetime_IST
from (select @report_term:=concat(day(metal_price_datetime_IST), ' ', monthname(metal_price_datetime_IST), ' ', year(metal_price_datetime_IST)) as report_term
           , metal_price_datetime_IST
           , metal_price
           , metal_id
           , case when @report_term=@old_report_term then @rn1:=@rn1+1  else @rn1:=1 end as rn
           , @old_report_term:=@report_term
      from metal_prices
      cross join (select @rn1:=0, @old_report_term:='') inituservar1
      where metal_price_datetime_IST BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND LAST_DAY('2018-02-01')
      order by metal_id, report_term, metal_price asc) lowp
inner join (select @report_term2:=concat(day(metal_price_datetime_IST), ' ', monthname(metal_price_datetime_IST), ' ', year(metal_price_datetime_IST)) as report_term
           , metal_price_datetime_IST
           , metal_price
           , metal_id
           , case when @report_term2=@old_report_term2 then @rn2:=@rn2+1  else @rn2:=1 end as rn
           , @old_report_term2:=@report_term2
      from metal_prices
      cross join (select @rn2:=0, @old_report_term2:='') inituservar1
      where metal_price_datetime_IST BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND LAST_DAY('2018-02-01')
      order by metal_id, report_term, metal_price desc) highp
 on lowp.rn=highp.rn
 and lowp.metal_id = highp.metal_id
 and lowp.report_term = highp.report_term
 and lowp.rn = 1
 and (lowp.metal_id = 1 or lowp.metal_id = 2)
 order by lowp.metal_price_datetime_IST DESC
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what the expected output is. Highest and lowest price for each date and type?

Comment: No,  i have those. I need the start and last price for each day and of both types...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you have in your fiddle seems too complex for what needs to be done. I have refactored and rewritten the query. Basically, the query is split in two parts. First one `maxminprice` determines the max and min price for each day for each metal. Fairly straight forward. The second part `firstlastprice` is a bit more complex. It finds out the max and min time stamps for each metal for each day. Then joins back to the main table to get the values for those time stamps. The `case` statement there is to merge the results for max and min (first and last) time so we don't have to do the query twice.

```
SELECT maxminprice.metal_id, 
       maxminprice.metal_price_datetime, 
       maxminprice.max_price, 
       maxminprice.min_price, 
       firstlastprice.first_price, 
       firstlastprice.last_price 
FROM   (SELECT metal_id, 
               DATE(metal_price_datetime) metal_price_datetime, 
               MAX(metal_price)           max_price, 
               MIN(metal_price)           min_price 
        FROM   metal_prices 
        GROUP  BY metal_id, 
                  DATE(metal_price_datetime) 
        ORDER  BY metal_id, 
                  DATE(metal_price_datetime)) maxminprice 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT mp.metal_id, 
                          day_range.metal_price_datetimefl, 
                          SUM(CASE 
                                WHEN TIME(mp.metal_price_datetime) = first_time 
                              THEN 
                                mp.metal_price 
                                ELSE NULL 
                              END) first_price, 
                          SUM(CASE 
                                WHEN TIME(mp.metal_price_datetime) = last_time 
                              THEN 
                                mp.metal_price 
                                ELSE NULL 
                              END) last_price 
                   FROM   metal_prices mp 
                          INNER JOIN (SELECT metal_id, 
                                             DATE(metal_price_datetime) 
                                             metal_price_datetimefl, 
                                             MAX(TIME(metal_price_datetime)) 
                                             last_time, 
                                             MIN(TIME(metal_price_datetime)) 
                                             first_time 
                                      FROM   metal_prices 
                                      GROUP  BY metal_id, 
                                                DATE(metal_price_datetime)) 
                                     day_range 
                                  ON mp.metal_id = day_range.metal_id 
                                     AND DATE(mp.metal_price_datetime) = 
                                         day_range.metal_price_datetimefl 
                                     AND TIME(mp.metal_price_datetime) IN 
                                         ( last_time, first_time ) 
                   GROUP  BY mp.metal_id, 
                             day_range.metal_price_datetimefl) firstlastprice 
               ON maxminprice.metal_id = firstlastprice.metal_id 
                  AND maxminprice.metal_price_datetime = 
                      firstlastprice.metal_price_datetimefl
```

Comment: yes, your correct... i applied the same query for my monthly report to a daily....  as a day would just have a day... Thanks..

Comment: thanks... how would i do this per monthly basis?  i.e for march 2017..?

Comment: It would be a similar query with different group by.

Comment: done this now.. works perfect for metal id = 1... but when i switch to metal_id= 2, it doesnt work... its weird.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca4867/18    however, for metal id =2 , it will work if the date range is beyond the same month,  as in BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND LAST_DAY('2018-03-01')

Comment: Please ask another question for help with that since it's a new direction.

Comment: i have,: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950664/mysql-min-and-max-per-month-as-oppose-to-daily

Comment: @DeanChambers Answered the question on that link. Check it out. :)